# Installing Arch Linux on a i686 CPU?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, system-installation

Trying to install Arch on an i686 CPU laptop, however it looks like Arch no longer supports this hardware. My question is does anyone know if it's possible to install an older version of Arch? If so please point out the best place to download a clean copy?

Answer (score 1):

Archlinux32.org is a "community maintained continuation of 32-bit support for Arch Linux". I wouldn't recommend installing an older, unsupported version of Arch, or any Linux distro for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take a look at the official news **[1]**

The 32-bit *soul* of Arch Linux moved into an alternative community-maintained fork named **Arch Linux 32** **[2]**; here you can find all resources needed.

---

**[1]** https://www.archlinux.org/news/the-end-of-i686-support/
**[2]** https://archlinux32.org/